# Count all unique instances of a string starting with www

Tags: python, regex

Im new to Python. Im trying to write a script that browses through a file and counts all unique occurences of string starting with www.

For example, say my file has

```
www_1.youtube.com      
www_1.youtube.com      
www_3.google.com    
www_1.youtube.com
```

Expected output:

www_1.youtube.com - 3
www_3.google.com - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your file is name file1.
You can use a dictionary to with the string as key, and store the count as the value. If you encounter the same string again, increment the value for that string. If you encounter a new string, add the string as a new key to the dictionary and set its value to 1. This is one way of doing. Might not be the best.

```
import re
file1 = "abc.txt"

with open(file1) as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content.split('\n') #split content into lines

count = dict()
for c in content:
    if re.match('^www', c):  #check if string starts with 'www'
        if c in count:
            count[c] += 1  #update existing string key
        else:
            count[c] = 1   #add new string key

print count
```

Output:

```
{'www_1.youtube.com': 3, 'www_3.google.com': 1}
```

Comment: how can I modify this if i dont want to use the entire line as key i.e I just want to use www_1 to be used as the key instead of the whole url

Comment: Use `c = c.split('.')[0]` after `if re.match('^www', c):`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your file content in list contains each lines are list of elements. Then with `startswith` you can filter your choices and with `colllections.Counter` you can easly find count of elemnts, it will be a dict .

Here a try :

```
import collections
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(collections.Counter([i.strip() for i in lines if i.startswith("www")]))
```

The o/p will be like :

```
Counter({'www_1.youtube.com': 3, 'www_3.google.com': 1})
```

Comment: is there something more I need here . I see this error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'

Comment: @DeepG Did you import collections ? Are you using python 2.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

very simply feeding generator comprehension to `collections.Counter`, counting the first word (splitting on dots):

```
import collections
with open("file.txt") as f:
   c=collections.Counter(l.split(".")[0] for l in f if l.startswith("www"))
```

result:

```
Counter({'www_1': 3, 'www_3': 1})
```